# Mongoose remove a Schema property after creating virtual property

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am creating a `groupedMenu` virtual property that replaces the need for my `menu` property.

So once I am done mapping my virtual property, I want to delete the menu key in my Schema.

Example Schema:

```
 new Schema({
    menu: [{
      category: String
    }]
 })
```

Example virtual category being created:

```
Restaurants.virtual('groupedMenu')
    .get(function () {
        return _.groupBy(this.menu, menu => menu.category);
    });
```

I've tried deleting the menu in my route, but it does not work. Example:

```
router.get('/someRoute', function (req, res) {
    Schema.findOne({})
        .then(menuStuff => {
            delete menuStuff.menu // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            return res.status(200).json(menuStuff);
        })
```

How can I delete my `menu` key after my my virtual property `groupedMenu` has been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues I see.

1. `Schema.findOne({})` looks quite weird. It should be `Model.findOne({})`.
2. The synonym to `virtual` is `getter`. This means that when you call `object.groupedMenu` the virtual method gets executed. In other words, the `groupedMenu` is using the `menu` every time you call `.groupedMenu`. **The virtual properties are not created, they are always executed at runtime.**

My suggestion here is to override the `Schema.toObject` so that it does not have the `.menu`

```
Schema.set("toObject", {
    virtuals: true,
    transform(doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret.menu;
    }
});
```

and use it within your code:

```
return res.status(200).json(menuStuff.toObject());
```

Comment: woops, yeah that should have been Model., good idea, I'll try it out. Thanks! edit - yep it works, great solution, thank you